# Error message display while edit any page in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, publishing-site, publishing-page

Today I am getting wired error when I am trying to edit any page in my SharePoint Online environment.

Error display like

> Sorry, something went wrong
>
> An unexpected error has occurred.

I don't know what happen with my SharePoint environment. I searched and got a solution from [Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2796622) but it doesn't work for me.

[image]

Comment: Most likely your issue is with master page. Reset the master page back to site definition.

Answer (score -3):

This is a pretty generic error in SharePoint that can be caused by any number of things. You can take a look a the Web Parts Maintenance Page by adding "**?content=1**" to the URL of your page. If you recently added a web part to the page or some other customization, this will allow you to turn it off.

More than likely though, you will have to do some digging. Whenever you in that page and get an error, you get a correlation id like in your example above. You can dig deep into the logs by finding them (typically in **C:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\web server extensions\15\logs**). Look for the most recent file and do a search it in and see if you can find that correlation id. If you can't find it you might try the previous log. When you find matching entries for the correlation id, you should get some idea to the component that is failing and causing your issues.

Comment: You can not reach the log files in Online!

Comment: As I mentioned it's a generic error message and not related whether it's on premise or online. the other option which mentioned as well to use "?content=1" and remove the web part that cause the issue.

Comment: Half of your answers is targeted at describing how to find and dig in the ULS logs that are not available Online

Comment: how can we fetch the logs in SP online ?

Comment: and its contents=1